# How to solve None return error when using external API in Python Flask app?

Tags: json, python-3.x, api, flask

In my Flask app (Python version is 3.6), I need to make a request to `heroku` web server to get some json-formatted response. Let's see a function to be called whenever server gets such a request:

```
@app.route("/get/camera/<id>")
def get_camera_by_id(id):
    from models import Camera
    try:
        camera=Camera.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
        return jsonify(camera.serialize())
    except Exception as e:
        return(str(e))
```

It returns json data, alright. Then my app sends this request to pull out a camera object info:

```
@app.route('/get/url')
def pull_url():
    cam = request.args.get('https://some-app.herokuapp.com/get/camera/2')
    return str(cam)
```

The function above belongs a public api, no permission issues should be considered here. Please note I simplified definitely last function though it might be sufficient to solve this case. Problem I'm stuck at emerges as my app gets `None` object instead of json response from `heroku` server. Surely, using same url in browser search mask looks to be perfect - I can see a pretty json stuff displayed there. I just start doing web apps by Flask (Python also), so it seems to be a lack of comprehension why that all goes wrong. Any clues will be much appreciated, of course.

Comment: trying this way ? `from flask import requests,json` then `cam_response = requests.get('your url here')` and `cam_data = json.loads(cam_response)`

Comment: it still gets wrong with this error in log: `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'NoneType'`. Weirdly, server response is nothing though object data remains present in database

Comment: @Codenewbie, I missed typing `requests` instead `request` originally, sorry. Editing `cam_data = json.loads(cam_response)` to be `cam_data = json.loads(cam_response.text)` works finely to see a string as a response I wanted. So, your solution is just what I needed, thanks a lot. You may post it as an answer to be accepted here.

Comment: glad i could help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done as:

```
from flask import requests,json
```

now using requests get the response from `URL` as:

```
cam_response = requests.get('your url here......')
```

For JSON to python objects you could do this :

```
cam_data = json.loads(cam_response)
```